# PHP Login Script - Require a seperate landing page for each user

Tags: php

I have currently uploaded a simple php login script, which is provided over here

This login package comes with 1 sql file, and simple PHP code which takes the user to logged_in.php once logged in, else it would remain at not_logged_in.php (pretty basic).

It also comes with a functioning register page (very simple one).

On which page would i need to edit, and what code would i use to make it so the user1 gets a different landing page to user2.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

```
// ... ask if we are logged in here:
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
// the user is logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
// for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are logged in" view.
include("views/logged_in.php");

} else {
// the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
// for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
include("views/not_logged_in.php");
```

I want to enter user1's logged in page into the sql table and fetch it so it goes to whatever that link is, once that user has logged in.

Comment: This has been posted twice. We don't know how to help you but if you even if we know the scenario but we need to see at least a part of your code that redirects user who login in your landing page.

Comment: Don't create multiple accounts and ask the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login script page where you do the authentication of the user, you can take user1 after authenticating to a different landing page than user2. One way is to store the page name of user where he/she will go after authentication in sql itself and retrieve it when logging in. And then use it in `header('location:<mysql_value')`. But that will create each page for user. And that's very redundant.

Here

```
// ... ask if we are logged in here:

if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {

$page = "SELECT page_name from users WHERE userid='$loggedin_userid'";
$query = mysql_query($page);
$page_name = mysql_result($query,0);
if($page_name){ header("location:'$page_name'"); //or include($page_name);}

} else {
// the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
// for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

But the catch remains. You have to physically create page for each user.

My Code:

```
// include the configs / constants for the database connection
require_once("config/db.php");

// load the login class
require_once("classes/Login.php");

// create a login object. when this object is created, it will do all login/logout stuff automatically
// so this single line handles the entire login process. in consequence, you can simply ...
$login = new Login();

// ... ask if we are logged in here:

if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {

$page = "SELECT landing_page from users WHERE userid='$user_id'";
$query = mysql_query($page);
$landing_page = mysql_result($query,0);
if($landing_page){ header("location:$landing_page"); }

} else {
// the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
// for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want to do, what i want to know is, how do i make the script go to user1's logged in page? Currently the code is as follows, but i want it to fetch from the sql row for the user:. EDIT: Ive added it to the original post.

Comment: Sorry, if the column in my sql table is landing_page, should this replace page_name? also the loggedin_userid, should that be.. the username id in SQL? I'm still getting a blank page.

Comment: Yes. I just showed you the example. You need to change values according to your own namings what you have used. :)

Comment: Just added my version of the code to your post sorry. I cant figure out why its remaining blank., btw what properties should the landing_page column be in SQL? I've set it as TEXT. Sorry im a newbie at SQL. I think the primary key needs to be linked maybe? Please let me know.

Comment: @user3654802 Please add any additional code to your question, not to an answer :)

Comment: No primary key is not an issue unless you are using conflicting names for userid. In that case i suggest using your primary key in WHERE clause instead of userid. Text is also fine. But you should prefer VARCHAR. I made edit to my answer after testing it on my server. Its working fine on my server. Have you checked your class for errors? If you dont get any errors, try turning on error reporting in php by using error_reporting(E_ALL) function in your script. Check for any errors and tell me.

Comment: Can i get the files from your server, and then i will edit it to my liking?

Comment: Its blank when i open it.

Comment: Sorry Server Problem. Go here: [Download Sample.php](http://zhyder007.0fees.net/uploads/sample.php)

Comment: How do i make it so that "$loggedin_userid = 'zee'; //your userid" this value is fetched from the login box, would it be using the $login = new Login(); value from our original example? Please let me know the exact context i should put in  "$loggedin_userid = 'zee'; //your userid" Thanks.

Comment: And you also did SELECT page from pagename WHERE , what is pagename

Comment: You need to use an HTML form that gets value from text input box and feeds it to your this script using GET/POST Method. Then in your script append $loggedin_userid=$_REQUEST['userid']. Do you know how to transfer data using GET/POST requests in html?

Comment: pagename is the name of the table. The structure of SQL query is: SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE <condition>. I think you should first learn all basics and then try this stuff. :)

Comment: Given the code in another page i can see :         

// check login form contents
        if (empty($_POST['user_name']))

Using this, what would i replace $loggedin_userid = 'zee'; with?

Comment: Where are you storing $_POST['user_name'] value in that page? Are you assigning it to any other variable?

Comment: There is this:                         // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your server)
                        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                        $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;

Comment: got this as well:         // create/read session, absolutely necessary
        session_start();

        // check the possible login actions:
        // if user tried to log out (happen when user clicks logout button)
        if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {
            $this->doLogout();
        }
        // login via post data (if user just submitted a login form)
        elseif (isset($_POST["login"])) {
            $this->dologinWithPostData();
        }
    }

Comment: it seems you are storing username in session. Add session_start() at the top of your above script. And then set $loggedin_userid = $_SESSION['user_name']

Comment: Hey Zeeshan, I am unable to chat as i have less than 13 reputation. Please get back to me with a point of contact and i want to offer an amount of gratitude to you if you can sort this issue out. Please get back to me ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: sure. here's my facebook profile link: [Zeeshan Hyder](http://facebook.com/zzeesshhaann)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways of doing this given your simple script.

1) Change logged_in.php to check what user is logged in and forward them to the individualized landing page based on some map or however you are planning on handling that.

2) Change the log_in function to return what page the user should be forwarded to rather than a boolean (**making an assumption here**). The recieving page would then forward the user based on whether they successfully looged in or not.

3) Change the log_in function to forward the user to the appropriate page for that user whether that is a landing page or a failure page.

In your situation I would probably go with **#3** since its the most straight forward implementation.